# as.raw and other as.* functions drops the dimension attribute when applied to arrays

Tags: r, arrays, type-conversion

I seem to have a simple problem in R which I've found no simple solution for: I would like to convert an array of integers to raw. Conversion between other simple types have a similar problem. I have found the following non-elegant solutions:

1. use as.raw and create a new array with the old dimensions:

```
a <- array(255:261,c(2,3))
b <- array(as.raw(a),dim(a))
```

2. use as.raw and reset the dimension attribute:

```
a <- array(255:261,c(2,3))
b <- as.raw(a)
dim(b) <- dim(a)
```

3. change the storage mode

```
a <- array(255:261,c(2,3))
b <- a
storage.mode(b) <- "raw"
```

All solutions are really complex for something that should be simple. In solution 1 and 2 as.raw (as other as.* functions) deletes the dim attribute, hence it must be reset. Solution 2 and 3 do not directly support the functional programming style, i.e., they do not return a copy of `a` with the new type, and, thus, cannot be used easily with piping. I can, of course, make a new function to support functional programming, but my guess is that I'm overlooking something basic. Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways to convert the type are:

```
b <- "dim<-"(as.raw(a), dim(a))

b  <- "storage.mode<-"(a, "raw")

b <- apply(a, 2, as.raw)
```

if the types are compatible, what as.raw is not, you can use:

```
a[]  <- as.double(a)
```

Data:

```
a <- array(55:61,c(2,3))
```

A not recommended way (thanks to comment from @Roland), as `raw` is an implicit class, setting it explicitly might have unexpected consequences, is:

```
b <- a; class(b) <- "raw"
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the second approach. "raw"  is an implicit class, setting it explicitly might have unexpected consequences.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that all your suggestions work with piping, and I favour `apply`. However, I would say that my thesis still stands: R needs a simple type-conversion mechanism that respect the dimension of arrays.

Comment: As you wrote, you can make a new function with simple type-conversion mechanism that respect the dimension like: `aas.raw  <- function(x) "storage.mode<-"(x, "raw")`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using your last approach. If the concern is functional programming, well `storage.mode<-` is a function.

```
"storage.mode<-"(a, "raw")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   ff   00   00
#[2,]   00   00   00
#Warning message:
#out-of-range values treated as 0 in coercion to raw 

a
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  255  257  259
#[2,]  256  258  260
```

Comment: Thanks Roland and GKi, before this discussion I did not know that "attribute<-" is a function. The notation is certainly short and convoluted.